# Dovecot TLS Handshake not working

Tags: ssl, dovecot, tls

I have set up my mailserver using http://workaround.org/ispmail and it worked until today, where I can not access the server using IMAP. 
The error I see in `dovecot.log` is

```
2012-02-09 16:37:40 imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts): rip=*myip*, lip=*serverip*, TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094417:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert illegal parameter
```

But do anybody know, how I can fix it so I do not need to read the e-mail using webmail, 'cause I can connect to the server using webmail (Squirrelmail)

I tried to change the setting in Thunderbird to not use SSL/TLS and just use clear password, but that did not do the trick